# How to convert a malformed bytes to dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Kafka consumer which reads the bytes and I need to treat it as a dictionary.
This is how the producer publishes:

```
def on_status(self, status):
    print "on_status"
    if status.retweeted:
      return
    tweetText = status.text.encode('utf8')
    created_at = status.created_at
    id = status.id
    if (re.findall(self.httpCheck, tweetText) or re.findall(self.httpsCheck, tweetText)):
      return
    if (re.search('[a-zA-Z]', tweetText)):
      try:
        self.idSelf += 1
        self.tweet["tweet"] = tweetText
        self.tweet["id"] = id
        self.tweet["sequence"] = self.idSelf
        self.tweet["created_at"] = created_at
        future = producer.send('bubble-test', bytes(self.tweet))
      except Exception as e:
        print e
      finally:
        producer.flush()
```

This is how consumer treats the bytes data:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('bubble-test', bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092', auto_offset_reset='earliest')
    for message in consumer:
        tweet = ast.literal_eval(message.value)
        print (type(tweet))
        sys.exit()
```

While using ast.literal_eval(), I get the following error:

> ValueError: malformed node or string: b'{\'created_at\':
>   datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 25, 13, 35, 11), \'tweet\': "RT @KKRiders:
>   Mavi to bowl the first ball of #Qualifier2. Saha on strike. Let\'s
>   go!\n\n#SRHvKKR #TeesraVaar #KKRHaiTaiyaar", \'id\':
>   1000007371131764736, \'sequence\': 1}'

How do I treat it as a dictionary, which is my end result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('bubble-test', bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092', auto_offset_reset='earliest')
    for message in consumer:
        tweet = (message.value)
        tweet.replace('\n', '\\n')
        tweet = eval(tweet)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ast.literal_eval` has three problems with this message

- it needs text instead of bytes - use `decode('utf-8')`
- it needs `\\n` instead of `\n` - use `replace("\n", "\\n")`
- it can't evaluate `datetime` object because it can evalueate only strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None. (doc: [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval))
  But you can remove string `datetime.datetime` and you get typle which
  can be evaluated. After evaluation you can convert tuple do datetime
  back.

.

```
import datetime
import ast

data = b'{\'created_at\': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 25, 13, 35, 11), \'tweet\': "RT @KKRiders: Mavi to bowl the first ball of #Qualifier2. Saha on strike. Let\'s go!\n\n#SRHvKKR #TeesraVaar #KKRHaiTaiyaar", \'id\': 1000007371131764736, \'sequence\': 1}'

data = data.decode('utf-8')
data = data.replace('\n', '\\n')
data = data.replace('datetime.datetime', '')

data = ast.literal_eval(data)

data['created_at'] = datetime.datetime(*data['created_at'])

print(data['created_at'])
print(data['tweet'])
```

Comment: I have only your `bytes` from error message - maybe `message.value` is different object and it doesn't works as `bytes`.

Answer (score 0):

`ast.literal_eval` doesn’t support `datetime` objects.  For naïve objects like this, you can send a tuple of its attributes instead, and reconstitute it with `datetime.datetime(*attrs)` on the other side.  If pickling is an option, you might try that instead; it supports such objects already.